# Understanding on-screen keyboard dingus when hardware keyboard attached

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard

We have an iPad education app with control buttons near the bottom-left and bottom-right of the screen.  Our app also occasionally uses the keyboard.  When the user has a hardware keyboard, the on-screen "dingus" (for lack of a better term) appears, to provide keyboard options (emoji etc).  Said dingus hides our buttons.  Our users are little kids, and they get confused (not realizing they can move it to the other side of the screen).

Ideally I'd like to hide the dingus completely.  It doesn't serve a value in this context.  I'm not seeing a way to do so, nor does that surprise me.  Saving that, I'd like to get the frame of the dingus when shown, so I can move the app's buttons out of the way.  Unfortunately the `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` doesn't fire or provide data when the dingus appears.

My questions:

1. What's the proper name of this dingus?
2. Is there any way to hide the dingus, preferably programmatically but even via the Settings app?
3. Is there any way to be notified when the dingus appears, and/or determine its frame?

[image: Screenshot with an arrow pointing to keyboard dingus in the lower right corner]

Comment: My guesses are: 1. "dingus" 2. No 3. No.